# Google App Script Pivot Group Rule with Intervals

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

From Google Sheets interface it is possible to create a pivot table grouped by value intervals as shown in the image below (going from left table to the right one):
[image: Google Sheets - Pivot Grouping Rule]

The above menu option prompts the user to specify the min, max and interval as below which results in the table on the right side:

[image]

MY Question: Is it possible to achieve the same through Google App Script? I can get the table on the left above using App Script but need to convert it to the one on the right via script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service has't methods to handle pivot tables but the Google Sheets API has them and are accessible by enabling it as an advanced service.

References

- [Pivot Tables | Google Sheets API V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables)
- [Google Advanced Services | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

Comment: Yes, I used the advanced service from Apps Script to access Sheets API to generate the above pivot. My question was more on how to create the grouping as shown in the image on the right table from the left table using the same API.

Comment: @PiyushGoel : Please edit the question and add there those details.

Comment: my stackoverflow account is new and sadly does not have edit permissions yet. But actually the last line on my question states - "I can get the table on the left above using App Script but need to convert it to the one on the right via script as well."